# Search Form Not Working

Tags: theme-development, search, theme-twenty-twelve

I'm using a basis of the Twenty Twelve theme and I'm using the below script (yes I know that the wrappers are not correct as yet).

However it's defaulting back to the main page. Any ideas?

```
<?php
/**
* The template for displaying Search Results pages.
*
*/ get_header(); ?>

<section id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <header class="page-header">
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'Clearwatch' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
        </header>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'Clearwatch' ); ?></h1>
            </header>

            <div class="entry-content">
                <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'Clearwatch' ); ?></p>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </article><!-- #post-0 -->

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</section><!-- #primary -->
```

Well guys, I double checked my search form and it had `index.php` in below:

So I changed it to my `search.php` path and it appears to be searching but defaulting back to my own website theme? Any ideas?

```
  <form id="searchform" method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/Clearwatch/search.php">
```

Comment: Is the file called "search.php"?

Comment: hi Jake, yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive actually solved this. It appears that there were some errors in the search.php file which resulted in lots of issues.

Thanks for your comments.